# downgrade from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0 to Version 1.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

By Mistake i updated my references and it affected the identity.framework , i did some research and it's totally a new different version and i need to do a lot of things to make it work, so i decided to switch back to version 1.0.0.0 which worked good for me. but now i got this error message:

> error 0004: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: Check your Web.config files. There might be a left-over conversion in one of those.

Comment: I looked there but not sure exactly what to do. can you explain more please

Comment: I'm not familiar with AspNet.Identity, so I'm not sure what I'd be looking for. Typically, there are dependencies that it injects throughout so that the framework will be able to be utilized throughout the project. There might a namespace added in the View's Web.config. Perhaps the EntityFramework configuration section has a bad reference now, or maybe a `defaultProvider` in `profile`, `membership`, or `roleManager`.

Comment: i looked and looked but cannot find anything

Comment: What do you mean by : EntityFramework configuration section has a bad reference now? can you be more specific?

Comment: There's a section in the main Web.config that deals with saying what version of EF to use. Like I said, I haven't used AspNet.Identity, so I don't know what all that entails, but I saw in your code that you use the EntityFramework from there. Check out [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556606.aspx) to see what I mean about the EF config section.

Comment: Here's my config setting:


<section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyTo

Comment: Thanks  krillgar you were right , it was about the EF version after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 8 hours troubleshooting this problem i finally figured out what was the problem.
The error message is a little misleading , because the problem is not about Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework itself but it was about "one of its dependencies" . it was the EF. i had three projects and each project on the solution has a different version of the EF . 6.0.0,6.0.1 and 6.1.0 i think . I uninstalled all of them and left the version 6.0.0 and it works fine now.